# How to add custom tooltip to nivo chart?

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a stream chart with Nivo (nivo(.dot)rocks)) in react.js. How to customize the tooltip? The documentation doesn't talk about this point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in nivo Line chart type case that works for me:

```
 <ResponsiveLine
  data={data}
  tooltip={point => {
    return <div>{point}</div>;
  }}
/>
```

Comment: point is not a vaild React child , use any of its properties instead, like id for example

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps someone, because for my package version (0.79.1), `tooltip` didn't do anything at all. I found that there's a prop called `sliceTooltip` that seems to function the same way. I have no idea what the difference is supposed to be, but it's the only one that allowed me to write a custom tooltip component for ResponsiveLine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can kick start by something like this

```
<ResponsiveLine
    data={data}
    tooltip={({ point }) => {
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    background: 'white',
                    padding: '9px 12px',
                    border: '1px solid #ccc',
                }}
            >
                <div>x: {point.x}</div>
                <div>y: {point.y}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }} 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For nivo node network componenent specifically *the data.name is the property here

```
 nodeTooltip={({node}) => {
            return <div>{node.data.name}</div>;
    }}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).